# Puppeteer Failing To Launch Browser

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, pdf-generation

I am currently working on an AWS Lambda that generates a PDF from HTML. The lambda is working perfectly once deployed however I would like to get it to run locally to make development easier.

I have installed SAM from AWS as well as Docker which AWS says will be needed to run a lambda locally.

In my solution folder in the command line I am running `sam local invoke "HelloWorldFunction" -e pdf/test-data/test.json` which then appears to work as it says that it is fetching it and then mounting it to the local docker container. However it then gives the following error:

[image: Error]
[image: Error]

Which appears to be an error about the puppeteer executable for chrome not existing even though it is in there. I am using the following variables:

```js
const chromium = require("chrome-aws-lambda");

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const pptr = require('puppeteer-core');
```

and then the code I am using to start the browser is the following:

```js
 const executablePath = event.isOffline
            ? "./node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/win64-737027/chrome-win/chrome.exe"
            : await chromium.executablePath;

browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
            args: chromium.args,
            defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
            executablePath: executablePath,
            headless: chromium.headless
        });
```

I have tried the settings given in the puppeteer troubleshooting, reinstalling my packages but nothing seems to work. My packages are also the following versions:

[image: Package Versions]

I haven't worked with docker before so I am not sure if that could be the problem? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I had to use the path provided by `chrome-aws-lambda`. So the code to generate the browser looks like this and it works:

```js
   browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
            args: chromium.args,
            defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
            executablePath: await chromium.executablePath,
            headless: chromium.headless
        });
```